# How do I get all distinct property names from a JSON column?

Tags: mysql, json

I have a MySQL JSON field with this content.

```
{"name": "Safari", "os": "Mac", "resolution": "1920x1080"}
{"name": "Firefox", "os": "PC", "resolution": "1920x1080"}
{"name": "Chrome", "os": "PC", "resolution": "1920x1080"}
```

I can get all browser names with this query.

```
SELECT browser->'$.name' browser FROM mytable;
Result = Safari, Firefox, Chrome
```

But how do I write a query that will give me "name", "os" and "resolution" as the result?

```
Result = name, os, resolution
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

You can use [`JSON_KEYS`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-search-functions.html#function_json-keys) to get a JSON array with the key names in it (which you would then need to parse in your application):

```
SELECT JSON_KEYS('{"name": "Safari", "os": "Mac", "resolution": "1920x1080"}')
```

Output:

```
["os", "name", "resolution"]
```

To get separate rows with the keys, you'd need MySQL 8+ and [`JSON_TABLE`](https://dev.mysql.com/doc/refman/8.0/en/json-table-functions.html#function_json-table):

```
SELECT *
FROM JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS('{"name": "Safari", "os": "Mac", "resolution": "1920x1080"}'),
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (key_name VARCHAR(20) PATH '$')
                ) AS k
```

Output:

```
key_name
os
name
resolution
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=88329799968a4b8ea5da6ee1e6fbdf3d)

To apply this to a table, you would `JOIN` the `JSON_TABLE` code above to the table and use the JSON column name in place of the JSON string e.g.

```
SELECT DISTINCT k.key_name
FROM test t
JOIN JSON_TABLE(JSON_KEYS(t.j),
                '$[*]' COLUMNS (key_name VARCHAR(20) PATH '$')
                ) AS k
```

[Demo on dbfiddle](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1ae39d30a33814bb2becc94de2ca3b0)

Comment: Yes I have MySQL 8+. Thanks for helping me out. Maybe I was a little unclear what I needed. The keys are not known beforehand so I need a query that give me the name of all DISTINCT keys.

Comment: @PeterKarlsson you would just replace the fixed JSON string I have used in my query with your column name. Nothing in the queries I have written depends on what the key names are...

Comment: @PeterKarlsson see this [demo](https://dbfiddle.uk/?rdbms=mysql_8.0&fiddle=a1ae39d30a33814bb2becc94de2ca3b0) showing the query getting the key names from the table

Comment: Thanks Nick. Exactly what I needed. Very kind of you.

Answer (score 1):

select the related  json attribute  name

```
SELECT browser->'$.name' name, browser->'$.os' os, browser->'$.resolution' resolution 
FROM mytable;
```

and if you need  distinct result add the distinct clause

```
SELECT DISTINCT browser->'$.name' name, browser->'$.os' os, browser->'$.resolution' resolution 
FROM mytable;
```